# How to install the Android SDK on Ubuntu14.10 64bit OS

Tags: permissions, android, 14.10, sdk

After completing the installation of android avd it shows `/home/murala/workspace/android/android-sdk-linux/tools/android: Permission denied`

How should I proceed?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! ;-) Next time, please use your [Shift] key for correct CaPiTaLiSaTiOn!  :-)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be having ownership issues with the file and/or folder.

Try the following commands -

`cd /home/murala/workspace/android`

`sudo chown -R murala:murala android-sdk-linux/`

Answer (score 0):

You apparently used the elevated access (`sudo`) to install in your personal and now are trying to use it as a normal user.

I would recommend that you install it in a sub-directory of /opt if you are going to use an elevated access for system wide, otherwise install it as a normal user without using the `sudo` prefix.

After this installation you can add the following to your PATH variable to use it:

```
$ export PATH=$PATH:/opt/android/sdk/tools:/opt/android/sdk/platform-tools
```

In this example the `sdk` would be the `android-sdk-linux` directory you have in your question above.

In direct response to your question, use the `sudo` (elevated) command to open it up in the /opt directory, then add the path to your PATH variable.